# How to make sudo -u not require password

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, sudo, ansible

I'm using ansible with vagrant and ansible is trying to sudo as postgres user to run some postgres commands.

Ansible running as vagrant user seems to run something like `sudo -u postgres psql`

This fails with error message `Missing sudo password`

I ssh onto the vm using the same vagrant user and try `sudo -u postgres psql` and sure enought it prompts for a password. Interestingly though, `sudo su postgres` switches to the postgres user without password.

Why would `sudo -u` require password when `sudo su` doesn't?

There is an entry in /etc/sudoers.d/ called vagrant that has the following contents:

```
%vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: I downvoted this because it shows no research. It basically amounts to will someone read the documentation for me.

Comment: Whilst I don't think your complaint is completely unfounded, I think you could be overestimating my ability to understand the research (which I had done). These are very new concepts and nuances in why it would work for sudo su and not sudo -u are not easy for a newbie like me to understand. @XavierLucas understood and explained this nuance very succinctly.

Comment: question seems fair enough to me, if everyone was an expert then why have this site? its a tricky area and the syntax of the config file has gotchas

Comment: Not every expert will have expertise in *all* fields of system administration.  But you are expected to be professional at some aspects of sysadmin, and done your homework in areas where you're having problems, before posting here; as [the rubric](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) says, "*Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you try to impersonate user postgres while your sudoers file let you impersonate user root from system group vagrant. When you use `sudo su` you also impersonate root.

Add this : `%vagrant ALL = (postgres) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Is there a way to allow the vagrant user to impersonate any user rather than add a line per user you want to impersonate?

Comment: @Max http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html

Comment: @Max Yes, replace (postgres) by (ALL). But it's a huge security breach, be careful with that. And be careful it's a group here, not user. So any user part of the vagrant group will have same privelges. Remove `%` if you want only the user vagrant to have these rights.

Comment: @XavierLucas, at the moment it can sudo as root which would be the greatest security concern right? Is allowing it to sudo to any user any worse? Going slightly off topic now..